# ダイアログに色を付けたい

Tags: javascript

ダイアログ１のボタンを押し、出てきた画面（OKやダイアログ１の背景など）を色を付けたいのですが、どなかたご教授いただけないでしょうか。

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<script>
    $(function(){
        $("#div-dialog1").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "ダイアログ１",
            buttons: {
                OK:function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        });
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $("#div-dialog1").dialog("open");
        });
    });

<body>
   <div id="div-dialog1">
       <p>ダイアログ１</p>
   </div>

<input type="button" id="button1" value="ダイアログ１" />
</body>
```

1行目を記入した結果画像の通り表示されたのですがOKやキャンセルの後ろの色を変えることは可能でしょうか？
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

やり方は2つあります、CSSのクラスを作って、そのクラスをダイアログのパラメーターに入れますか、直線CSSのスタイル追加する。

下記のコードを試してみて下さい
１行目の方法

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/themes/smoothness/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

  <script>
    $(function(){
        $("#div-dialog1").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "ダイアログ１",
            dialogClass: 'myTitleClass',
             buttons : [
                {
                    text:'OK',
                    class:'okBtn',
                    click: function() {
                        alert("OK");
                        $(this).dialog("close");                        
                    }                   
                },
                {
                    text:'CANCEL',
                    class:'cancelBtn',
                    click: function() {
                        $(this).dialog("close");
                    }                   
                }
            ]

        });
        
        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $("#div-dialog1").dialog("open");
        });
    });
    </script>
  
  <style>
    .myTitleClass .ui-dialog-titlebar {
        background:red;
    }

    .myTitleClass .ui-dialog-content {
        background:green !important;
    }
    
    .okBtn {
      background: blue !important;
    }
    
    .cancelBtn {
      background: yellow;
    }
  </style>

<body>
   <div id="div-dialog1">
       <p>ダイアログ１</p>
   </div>

<input type="button" id="button1" value="ダイアログ１" />
</body>
```

2行目の方法

```
  $(function(){
        $("#div-dialog1").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            modal: true,
            title: "ダイアログ１",
            buttons: {
                OK:function(){
                    $(this).dialog("close");
                }
            }
        }).prev(".ui-dialog-titlebar").css("background","red");

        $("#button1").click(function(){
            $("#div-dialog1").dialog("open");
        });
    });
```

追加:
バックグラウンドの色

```
.myTitleClass .ui-dialog, .ui-widget-content {
  background:antiquewhite !important
}
```